# Shiny and ggplot2 with multiple lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, tidyverse

I'm new to Shiny and have run into problems when I try to render a ggplot. I want to render a plot with multiple lines but I get the error: Warning: Error in : Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1)

It work fine when I render a single line, but not multiple. There are earlier questions on Stack Overflow adressing similar issues, but I'm afraid I dont fully understand their soulutions.

Help would be much appreciated. :)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

url <- paste("https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/sites/default/files/documents/COVID-19-geographic-disbtribution-worldwide-",format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-18"), ".xlsx", sep = "")
GET(url, authenticate(":", ":", type="ntlm"), write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")))
df <- read_excel(tf)

df  <- df %>%
        rename(country = countriesAndTerritories) %>% 
        arrange(country, dateRep) %>%
        group_by(country) %>%
        mutate(Cumulative_Death = cumsum(deaths)) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        filter(Cumulative_Death > 9) %>%
        group_by(country) %>%
        mutate(numbers_of_days = row_number(),
               First_Death_Date = min(dateRep)) %>% 
        select(country, numbers_of_days, deaths, Cumulative_Death)

ui <- fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Statistik Covid-19"),
        sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                selectInput("cou", "Country:", choices = unique(df$country), selected = "SWeden", multiple = TRUE),
                selectInput("var", "Variable:", choices = c("deaths", "Cumulative_Death"))),
        mainPanel(
                plotOutput("covid"))
        ))

server <- function(input, output, session){

        selected <- reactive(filter(df, country %in% input$cou))

        output$covid <- renderPlot({
                ggplot(selected(), aes(x=numbers_of_days, input$var, colour = input$cou)) +
                        geom_line(size = 1.5) +
                        labs(title = "Covid-19: Antal döda per 100 000 invånare",
                             x = "DAGAR SEDAN ANTAL DÖDSFALL ÖVERSTEG TIO",
                             y = paste0(input$var),
                             caption = "Source: European Centre for Disease Prevention and Control") +
                        guides(colour = guide_legend(title=NULL))
        })
        }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You are calling input$land in your server, but there is not reference in the UI for land. Please list the libraries you are using to speed up supporting this inquiry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. As @SusanSwitzer already mentioned. Main issue is that you use `input$land`. So. Simply replace with `input$country`. Second. Map `colour` on `country` which is the varname in the df. Third I switched to `aes_string` instead of `aes` to use the character inputs:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

url <- paste("https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/sites/default/files/documents/COVID-19-geographic-disbtribution-worldwide-",format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-18"), ".xlsx", sep = "")
httr::GET(url, httr::authenticate(":", ":", type="ntlm"), httr::write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")))
df <- readxl::read_excel(tf)

df  <- df %>%
  rename(country = countriesAndTerritories) %>% 
  arrange(country, dateRep) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(Cumulative_Death = cumsum(deaths)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(Cumulative_Death > 9) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(numbers_of_days = row_number(),
         First_Death_Date = min(dateRep)) %>% 
  select(country, numbers_of_days, deaths, Cumulative_Death)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Statistik Covid-19"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("country", "Country:", choices = unique(df$country), selected = "Sweden", multiple = TRUE),
      selectInput("var", "Variable:", choices = c("deaths", "Cumulative_Death"))),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("covid"))
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session){

  # input$country instead input$land
  selected <- reactive(filter(df, country %in% input$country))

  output$covid <- renderPlot({
    # switch to aes_string. map colour on country instead of input$land
    ggplot(selected(), aes_string(x = "numbers_of_days", y = input$var, colour = "country")) + 
      geom_line(size = 1.5) +
      labs(title = "Covid-19: Antal döda per 100 000 invånare",
           x = "DAGAR SEDAN ANTAL DÖDSFALL ÖVERSTEG TIO",
           y = paste0(input$var),
           caption = "Source: European Centre for Disease Prevention and Control") +
      guides(colour = guide_legend(title=NULL))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! :) May I ask why aes_string is used? I never seen it before.

Comment: My pleasure. With `aes_string` you can pass the varnames as strings to ggplot which makes it easier to use with `input$var` as it is a character.